# CSS position absolute - next positioned element is body?

Tags: css, position, absolute

Quoting from `msdn`:

> "Object is positioned relative to parent element's position—**or to
>   the body object if its parent element is not positioned**"

Lets say I set a div with certain dimension to bottom 0; and left: 0; it will not be positioned at the bottom of body but at bottom left of `viewport`. Also when giving body a margin - the div will still be at bottom left of `viewport`.

I know how to work with these properties but I am looking for reasoning. Is it not the body to which the absolute elem is positioned to when no other ancestor is positioned? Thanks!

Here is the fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/picbig/0p6rgv8f/

HTML:

```
<div id="large_box_greater_than_viewport"></div>
<div id="absolute_cnt"></div>
```

CSS:

```
body{
    margin-left: 200px;
}
#large_box_greater_than_viewport{
    width: 900px;
    height: 10000px;
    background: red;
}
#absolute_cnt{
    position: absolute;
    width: 65%;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 80px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.7);
}
```

Comment: As rblarson wrote: when position: relative is set on the body element it moves to bottom of body. But shouldn't that setting on the body be default according to msdn's statement (and many other sources stating the same)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Absolutely positioned elements are positioned relative to their containing block.

`fixed` positioned elements respect to the [initial containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details) which takes the dimensions of the [viewport](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#viewport).

> **Initial containing block**
>
> The containing block in which the root element lives is a rectangle
>   called the initial containing block. For continuous media, it has the
>   dimensions of the viewport and is anchored at the canvas origin; it is
>   the page area for paged media.

And `absolute` positioned elements respect to their containing block which is established by the nearest ancestor with a `position` of anything other than `static`. i.e. `fixed`, `absolute` or `relative`.

**The key point is:**

> If there is no such ancestor, the containing block is the initial
>   containing block.

Therefore that absolute positioned element inside `<body>` won't be placed with the respect to the `<body>` itself, but to the initial containing block, i.e. the viewport.

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#containing-block-details

Comment: should always read w3.org first before going to mdn, msdn...thanks

Answer (score 3):

You need to set the position of the body:

```
body{
    margin-left: 200px;
    position:relative;
}
```

Comment: Thats right - once body is set to position: relative; it moves to bottom of body but shouldn't that setting on the body be default according to msdn's statement (and many other sources stating the same)?

Comment: I believe the default setting for all elements is `position:static;`

Comment: yes apart from body as I always believed at least - then a student of mine asked me that question and I could not give him an acceptable answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried some patterns in various browsers, and you are right!

The object is not positioned relative to the body unless the body is positioned too!

If the body is not positioned, the object is positioned relative to the viewport.

Answer (score -1):

1). Yes you can give position absolute to  tag, but you need to put that  tag inside another  tag with position relative.

2). Or you can do this with after before functionality.